# menu bar cshtml not display the way I want

Tags: c#, css, razor

I want to have the same menu bar as on w3school that can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_navbar.

However mine does not look like that. Mine looks like this.
[image: My menu bar]

Here is the html that I have generated

```
<body style="">

                                <div class="sidebar-menu">
                                   <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Home
                </a>
            </li>
                       <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    About Us
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Company Profile
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>

            </ul>
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/InventoryLocation/Index">
                    Inventory location
                </a>
            </li>
                       <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Sale/Sale">
                    Add Invoice
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Update Invice
                </a>
            </li>
                       <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Update Invice 1
                </a>
            </li>
                       <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Update Invice 2
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>

            </ul>

            </ul>
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Delete Invoice
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>

            </ul>
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Report/Report">
                    Report
                </a>
            </li>
                       <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Daily Report
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>
           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/Home/Index">
                    Monthly Report
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>

            </ul>

                    </div>

        <div class="container body-content">
```

Here is how I have generated the html in the cshtml file.

```
   @helper GetTreeMenus(IEnumerable<erp_colombia.Models.MenuMaster> siteMenu, Nullable<int> parentID)
    {
            foreach (var i in siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(parentID)))
            {
            var submenu = siteMenu.Where(a => a.ParentID.Equals(i.MenuID)).Count();

            string action = i.ActionName;
            string controller = i.ControllerName;

           <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li class="treeview">
                <a href="/@i.ControllerName/@i.ActionName">
                    @i.MenuText
                </a>
            </li>
            @GetTreeMenus(siteMenu, i.MenuID)
            </ul>
            }
            }
            @{
                if (Session["MenuList"] != null)
                {
                    <div class="sidebar-menu">
                        @GetTreeMenus(Session["MenuList"] as IEnumerable<erp_colombia.Models.MenuMaster>, 0)
                    </div>
                }
            }
```

And of course here is my css.

```
.treeview-menu{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

.treeview a {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.treeview a:hover {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think the fastest way would be to remove all html and css from your page and just copy paste w3school example, then step by step replace example elements on your custom so you will know when something whent wrong

Comment: css issue...give your generated html code from page source

Comment: @RabbyHasan I have remplaced my image of the generated code with the acctual code.

Comment: I assume this is MVC. Your CSS is clashing with in-built MVC CSS template that is why you are getting this issue. To override it replace the built-in CSS file with your CSS file in LayoutPage

Comment: @RohanRao when I added my generated code and css in w3school I get the same result. If you add my generated code in w3school you can try to get the same result but I was unable to do it.